The CrystalDecisions package is not visible to any other projects except the first one, why?
I have to maintain an old VB.NET ASP.NET WebForms app written years ago. I don't know what version of the .NET Framework it was originally written in, because whoever started it didn't put it into any version control. I've upgraded it to .NET Framework 4.5.2. Recently I migrated all of our TFS repos to GitHub. The original developer added all assemblies/packages using a common pattern from the 00, by adding the DLL to the project, then adding an Imports at the top of every .vb file that needed it. Because the project is now in GitHub, it no longer has the Packages folder that was off the root of the Visual Studio Solution. But that doesn't really matter, because VS re-creates the Packages folder.
Anyway, the problem I'm experiencing is the original developer put the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine into multiple projects. I added it to the first project that complained about CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine not being there, using this syntax:
NuGet\Install-Package CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine -Version 1.0.0

Which I got off of NuGet.
The problem I'm encountering is I cannot use that same command in Package Manager Console, for any more VS projects. I'll get an error in the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.1.0.0 already exists, so it won't allow me to run it. I had thought that VS would put packages into separate folders for each project, but I'm wrong about that. And VS won't "see" CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine when I run it. (VS sees it find when I build it, but it won't when I debug it.)
Why does VS not see CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine in any of the other projects that uses CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine?
